# Obtain Timezone for US States that have more than one UTC offsets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, timezone

I have a JSON with a list of countries and their perspective provinces/states. Here's a short version (not showing all for the example). Im calling it **countries.json**:

```
{
  "USA": {
    "NH": "New Hampshire",
    "NJ": "New Jersey",
    "NM": "New Mexico",
    "NY": "New York",
    "NC": "North Carolina",
    "ND": "North Dakota",
    "OH": "Ohio",
    "OK": "Oklahoma",
    "OR": "Oregon",
    "PA": "Pennsylvania",
    "RI": "Rhode Island",
    "SC": "South Carolina",
    "SD": "South Dakota",
    "TN": "Tennessee",
    "TX": "Texas"
  },
  "Canada": {
    "ON": "Ontario",
    "QC": "Quebec",
    "NS": "Nova Scotia"
  }
}
```

My goal is to build the following form:

1. user selects country, then the "state/province" dropdown populates
2. user selects state/province, then the timezones populate
3. user selects timezone

The problem Im having is that there are certain states with different timezones. For example, Texas. Texas has two UTC offsets:

- UTC−06:00 CT
- UTC−07:00 MT

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_offsets_by_U.S._state

Using PHP and/or Javascript/jQuery how can I achieve this?

So far, I have the following:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select id="country"></select>
</div>
<div id="states_container"></div>
<div id="timezones_container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("countries.json", function (json) {
        $.each(json, function (k, v) {
            $("#country").append('<option value="' + k + '">' + k + '</option>');
        });

        $("#country").change(function () {
            var country_code = $(this).val();
            var states = json[country_code];
            var sel = '<label>States:</label><select>';
            $.each(states, function (k, v) {
               sel += '<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>';
            });
            sel += '</select>';
            $("#states_container").html(sel);
        });
    });
});
```

One idea was to use **PHP** in an AJAX request by using the following:

```
<?php
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "US");
var_dump($timezones);

/* Result */
/*
array (size=29)
  0 => string 'America/Adak' (length=12)
  1 => string 'America/Anchorage' (length=17)
  2 => string 'America/Boise' (length=13)
  3 => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
  4 => string 'America/Denver' (length=14)
  5 => string 'America/Detroit' (length=15)
  6 => string 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis' (length=28)
  7 => string 'America/Indiana/Knox' (length=20)
  8 => string 'America/Indiana/Marengo' (length=23)
  9 => string 'America/Indiana/Petersburg' (length=26)
  10 => string 'America/Indiana/Tell_City' (length=25)
  11 => string 'America/Indiana/Vevay' (length=21)
  12 => string 'America/Indiana/Vincennes' (length=25)
  13 => string 'America/Indiana/Winamac' (length=23)
  14 => string 'America/Juneau' (length=14)
  15 => string 'America/Kentucky/Louisville' (length=27)
  16 => string 'America/Kentucky/Monticello' (length=27)
  17 => string 'America/Los_Angeles' (length=19)
  18 => string 'America/Menominee' (length=17)
  19 => string 'America/Metlakatla' (length=18)
  20 => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
  21 => string 'America/Nome' (length=12)
  22 => string 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah' (length=27)
  23 => string 'America/North_Dakota/Center' (length=27)
  24 => string 'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem' (length=30)
  25 => string 'America/Phoenix' (length=15)
  26 => string 'America/Sitka' (length=13)
  27 => string 'America/Yakutat' (length=15)
  28 => string 'Pacific/Honolulu' (length=16)
*/
?>
```

But this gives me the timezones per country (US in this case), where as I need them to be by state and accounting for the UTC.

Would you guys have any idea on how to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Note:** I know there are API's that might be able to help, but I am looking for something local I can host on my own server.

Comment: You might just have to download a mapping from zipcode to timezone. The maintenance of it is going to be annoying. I doubt there are better solutions though. Btw you probably already now this: web client can tell you the timezone offset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

Comment: The two-dropdown approach is common (country, then time zone).  A three-dropdown approach can work, but only if you find and maintain a reliable source of data for time zones within sub regions.  Keep in mind that not every country with multiple time zones is subdivided by "states".